# How to show Notification body in upper side on Display when notification is comming?

Tags: java, android

In my Android Application i don't have a problem how to use notification in service. But i don't know how to show my notification in upper side of display and always on top of all activites when it's comming. For example, it happens when an incoming SMS message is received, the part of the status bar that is associated with the notification is temporarily shown in the upper part of the screen. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN9Yp.jpg)

Comment: Do you have an example image how it should look like? I will help you.

Comment: @DEX7RA I have added an image to the description. In different messengers, there is an equal response to incoming messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HOW TO MAKE A HEADS-UP NOTIFICATION**

For that we need a `NotificationCompat.Builder()` that requires a channel ID from a `NotificationChannel`.

The notification will only appears as a heads-up notification if the `NotificationChannel` is created with an importance value of `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH`:

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("channel01", "name", 
     NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);   // for heads-up notifications
channel.setDescription("description");

// Register channel with system
NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

Use this snippet to show the heads-up notification:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel01")
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
        .setContentTitle("Test")
        .setContentText("You see me!")
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)   // heads-up
        .build();

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

---

In addition I found a useful [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mW45toHZpg&ab_channel=Melardev) that you can follow along. It's sourcecode is provided in [github](https://github.com/melardev/TutsAndroidNotifications) as well.

**Result: Heads-up notification**

[image: Heads-up notification]